# Convert str to date python

Tags: python

I have a little problem, I know how to convert str to date but with this format `'Monday January 1'`, I cannot convert the string.

I tried that :

```
datetime_str = 'Monday January 1'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%A %B %d')
```

But the output is : `1900-01-01 00:00:00`

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing work ...

Comment: That output is correct, you never supplied a year

Comment: What do you want Python to do? Pick the most recent year in which January 1st was a Monday? What's your intended output?

Answer (score 2):

The date and month are being set correctly. You can provide the correct year yourself, by doing:

```py
datetime_str = 'Monday January 1'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%A %B %d')
datetime_object = datetime_object.replace(year=2021)
```

Comment: this does not make sense - the 1st of January 2021 was a Friday, not a Monday

Comment: For instance if i try this :
   `date = "January 01, 1990"`
    `datef = datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d, %Y')`

The output is `1900-01-01 00:00:00` and i don't know why

Comment: @AlanCUZON that code works. what's the issue?

Comment: @AlanCUZON it gives `1990`, not `1900`

Answer (score 0):

or you should give the year as string as well.

```
datetime_str = 'Monday January 1 2021'
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%A %B %d %Y')
```

Comment: same here, the input is actually invalid (2021-1-1 was a Friday); `%A` seems to be ignored

Comment: It is wrong to provide the wrong days of the week! Just giving `January 1 2021` is sufficient!